How to use rsync for Windows to create backups without permissions issues?
I tried to use rsync to backup my files to M2 SSD on Windows 11 Home like this:
rsync -ravh --delete /cygdrive/e/Test /cygdrive/f

Everything is fine, but I can't access directories and files on another PC because of "have no permissions".
Tried adding parameters.
--no-perms --no-owner --no-group --chmod=ugo=rwX
--chmod u+rwx

No effect. Is it possible to make rsync just copy files like Windows does, without interfering with security settings?!
P.S. Spent about an hour searching for a solution on the Internet, read a bunch of information about rsync, except solving my problem.
P.P.S. Tried rsync from https://www.rsync.net and https://www.cygwin.com -- same result.

"Is it possible to make rsync just copy files like Windows does, without interfering with security settings?" - No

It seems faster to write my own tool than to understand rsync...


Is it possible to make rsync just copy files like Windows does, without interfering with security settings?!

No, because it's not written to do so. You can tell because it's running via Cygwin, so it's best to think of it not as a Windows program, but as a Linux program running through a translation layer – it is only aware of POSIX permissions (and POSIX ACLs, but those translate poorly from Windows ACLs).
Use the Windows built-in robocopy instead.
